# Можно ли ограничить память для приложения на Go

Tags: golang

**Можно ли ограничить память потребляемой Golang допустим до 256мб?** Моя программа на `Golang` потребляет более `500 мб памяти`, на некоторых компьютерах может просто не быть столько памяти (**520мб**) Читал документацию и другие зарубежные `stackoverflow вопросы`, говорили что поможет в этом `MemStats` - *https://golang.org/src/runtime/mstats.go?s=6236:15651#L149* я почитал документацию, примеры. И нечего не понял... Кто-то может подробней обьяснить методы для лимитирования памяти?

Comment: А что именно вы хотите чтобы произошло, когда программа дойдёт до этого предела? В большинстве случаев, если у ОС нет достаточно ОП, а SWAP'а нету или недостаточно, она просто прибьёт процесс.

Comment: @Ainar-G убивать процесс мне не нужно, мне нужно что-то на подобии засыпания... когда программа исчерпывает лимит, она засыпает...память освобождается и дальше опять программа опять начинает свое действие. У меня просто работает функции на горутине, и это будет как раз кстати. Или есть иные варианты?

Comment: У вас какие-то странные представления о работе программ. Если процесс заснёт, память кто освобождать будет? Я вам рекомендую почитать про параметр GOGC, а также в целом о виртуальной памяти и работе ОС.

Answer (score 2):

MemStats - позволяет получить статистику использованой памяти, можно запустить проверку в отдельной горутине (по таймеру), и предпринимать нужные действия

```
package main
import (
    "runtime"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    memStats := &runtime.MemStats{}
    _ = make([]string, 1000000)

    runtime.ReadMemStats(memStats)
    fmt.Printf("\nAlloc = %v\nTotalAlloc = %v\nSys = %v\nNumGC = %v\n\n", memStats.Alloc / 1024, memStats.TotalAlloc / 1024, memStats.Sys / 1024, memStats.NumGC)
}
```

Но также, если Вам нужно контролировать другой процес на использование памяти, советую посмотреть тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522692/how-to-set-memory-limit-to-a-process-in-golang

### UPD

Также можно воспользоваться ограничением памяти с помощью ОС:

```
# Install cgroup-bin
apt-get install cgroup-bin

# Create a cgroup for memory and cpu called "mygroup"
cgcreate -g memory,cpu:mygroup

# Add 128 CPU shares (about 12% CPU).
echo 128 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/mygroup/cpu.shares

# Add 32MB of memory to the limit.
echo 32000000 > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/mygroup/memory.limit_in_bytes

# Do not allow the process to use swap (if the limit is reached the
# process will be killed instead).
echo 0 > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/build/memory.swappiness

# Run the command in the specified group.
cgexec -g cpu,memory:mygroup ./compute
```

Или запускать программу в **docker** (с ограничением по памяти), этот способ намного лучше тем, что он платформо независимый.

[Лимитирование ресурсов с помощью docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/)

[Лимитирование ресурсов в linux](https://www.antonlindstrom.com/2015/11/22/limit-processes-with-cgexec.html)

Comment: а можно просто ограничить текущее взаимодействия приложения с памятью до 200 мб ?

Comment: Такой возможности нет, разве кто-то оформил такое решение в отдельный package.

Comment: Есть альтернатива, использовать ограничение на основе ОС (или использовать Докер)

Comment: докер тут вообще не лезет, а ограничение на основе ОС как сделать?

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент [это невозможно](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16843),
если речь идёт об ограничении потребляемой памяти именно в программе
(а не системой *для* программы: это-то возможно, как показал Максим, но
приведёт к банальному прибитию программы `SIGKILL`-ом при превышении лимита по памяти).

Более подробно о проблеме можно почитать [тут](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zn4f3-XWmoHNj702mCCNvHqaS7p9rzqQGa74uOwOBKM/).

Из того, что можно сделать в самой программе, это "тюнинг"
параметра [`GOGC`, который приделали в 1.5](https://golang.org/s/go15gcpacing).

Грубо говоря, значение `GOGC` это кол-во процентов, на которое сборщик мусора
позволит вырасти текущему объёму хипа до того, как начать следующую сборку.

Значение по умолчанию 100 означает, что когда сборщик мусора собрал
мусор, и обнаружил, что занято 256 метров, след. сборка будет только по
достижении 256 + (100% от 256) = 512 метров.

След-но, уменьшая это значение, можно увеличивать "pacing" сборщика
и надеяться на лучшее.

Вообще же пока (вкл. текущую версию 1.9) единственный способ реально
ограничивать потребление памяти в нагруженной программе это
*ограничивать нагрузку* на неё.

Кроме того, тут следует понимать, что рантайм Go не отдаёт сразу всю
освобождённую память системе; он помечает свободные страницы спец.
хинтом (через `madvise(2)`) — так что система может их забрать, если
сильно нужно.
Проще говоря, нет особого смысла зарубать приложение лимитами:
они не знают про то, как работает сборка мусора в Go.